# How can I display time on title of text file

Tags: php

hello guys how I can display time in title of a text file here is my code :

```
 <?php
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
 header('Content-type: text/plain');
 ...
 ?>
```

I want the title of file could be like this test_ August 30, 2013.txt I hope someone could help me

Comment: `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test_'.date('F_j_Y').'.txt');`

Comment: please do not make duplicate questions, re-edit previous questions to improve it the way the on hold messages tell you to and then wait for a reopen vote.

Comment: ok I'm so sorry patrick evans it's my bad I won't do like this again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date` function, and I wouldn't use `spaces` or `,`.

```
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test_' . date('F_j_Y') . '.txt');
```